# JSON: Invalid Class Typecast in Delphi

Tags: json, delphi

This works, when it is an object:

```json
{"data":{"url":"stackoverflow.com"}}
```

This does not work, when it is an array:

```json
{"data":[{"url":"stackoverflow.com"}]}
```

> Error: Invalid class typecast

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  json : string;
  obj, data : TJSONObject;
  url : string;

begin
  json := '{"data":{"url":"stackoverflow.com"}}';
  obj := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(json) as TJSONObject;

  try
    data := obj.Values['data'] as TJSONObject;
    url := data.Values['url'].value;
    showMessage(url);
  finally
    obj.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I know I have to use `TJSONArray`, but I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

This is not hard to understand.

In the first case, the value of `data` is an object, so `obj.Values['data'] as TJSONObject` is correct.

In the second case, the value of `data` is an array, so `obj.Values['data'] as TJSONObject` is wrong. it needs to be `obj.Values['data'] as TJSONArray` instead, and then you access the `TJSONObject` from the elements of the array, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  json : string;
  obj, data : TJSONObject;
  arr: TJSONArray;
  url : string;

begin
  json := '{"data":[{"url":"stackoverflow.com"}]}';
  obj := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(json) as TJSONObject;

  try
    arr := obj.Values['data'] as TJSONArray;
    data := arr[0] as TJSONObject;
    url := data.Values['url'].Value';
    ShowMessage(url);
  finally
    obj.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Now I see it, pass it to an array and then access that position. Thanks!